# Run cronjobs in different timezones

Tags: server, cron, timezone

I have some cronjobs that I want to run. I want two of my scripts to run in UTC and the rest in CET. I have tried with cron_tz but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/374284

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CRON_TZ=Europe/Amsterdam
```

works. Mind though that it could be that specific Ubuntu's do not work with CRON_TZ. `man 5 crontab` tells you if it is supported. If it does not have this, then yours does not support it:

> The CRON_TZ variable specifies the time zone specific for the cron table. The user should enter a time according to the specified time zone into the table. The time used for writing into a log file is taken from the local time zone, where the daemon is running.

It probably does not and you should be using [systemd.timer](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html) and [systemd.time](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.time.html) and [calendar events](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.time.html#Calendar%20Events). Each unit holds its own timezomne so that will fix your problem.

Comment: I used CRON_TZ with capitals but thanks for the manual direction.

Comment: @needHelpToCode Ill remove it :D

Comment: right now I have a script like * * * * * CRON_TZ=UTC etc.., is this the way that it works?

Comment: no. CRON_TZ goes in a seperate line at the beginning of cron file (similar to PATH) if you want the SCRIPTS to run with a diff. timezone use @vidarlo answer. You can use TZ=UTC before the script to have the script use another timezone. Feel free to remove the upvote and upvote vidarlo ;)

Answer (score 2):

Preface the command with `TZ=CET`, or set the TZ environment variable

```
[~]$ TZ=UTC date
Thu Dec 15 14:53:51 UTC 2022
[~]$ TZ=CET date
Thu Dec 15 15:53:54 CET 2022
```

Comment: are you sure? afaik TZ only affects the scripts executed (so the TZ inside the scripts is set) and not when cron starts it.

Comment: I think the confusion is what he wants. I read the question as he wanting to run *the commands* in different timezones, not the *cron* itself.

Comment: hmmm :) that is one way of reading it yes _O- I focused too much on CRON_TZ

Comment: Probably means the question is somewhat unclear ;)

Comment: +1 ... Possible to read it that way